# I could not find linux-kernel-devel package

Tags: linux-kernel

I am using ubuntu 12.10, I want to customise my kernel. When I started installing the required  packages using

```
sudo apt-get install linux-kernel-devel fakeroot kernel-wedge build-essential
```

It returned the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-kernel-devel
```

is this package necessary? If so how to get it

Regards,

Tamil

Answer (score 0):

The compile the kernel you need the source code of the kernel.
You need the `linux-source` package to grab the latest kernel source package (available in Ubuntu).

For more details on tis package, check out the [package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal-updates/linux-source).